# How to change a password

Tags: password

I'm trying to change the password on my RPi 3. I've tried `sudo passwd` and it gets me to the screen where I can enter a new password, but then the terminal stops letting me type. Does anyone know how to work around this? I've also tried `sudo raspi-config` but that still doesn't do anything

Answer (score 11):

**Linux doesn't display anything when you type your password. no asterisks, no dots, no nothing.**

After entering `passwd` on the command line and pressing enter type your **password** at the command prompt, nothing will display but that's **ok**.

Raspberry pi [document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md) say:

> Enter **passwd** on the command line and press Enter. You'll be prompted
>   to enter your current password to authenticate, and then asked for a
>   new password. Press Enter on completion and you'll be asked to confirm
>   it. Note that no characters will be displayed while entering your
>   password. Once you've correctly confirmed your password, you'll be
>   shown a success message (passwd: password updated successfully), and
>   the new password will apply immediately.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't realize that Linux doesn't show your password when you type it.

Answer (score 9):

Do **NOT** type `sudo passwd` (unless you are trying to change the password of another user).

The command to change your password is `passwd`

Comment: If you do not remember the password and are trying to ssh into the pi, sometimes you need to use `sudo passwd pi`, to force changing the password without authenticating before hand with a password you do not know.